# Verifying the cocycle property

Tags: dynamical-systems

> > **Definition of cocycle:**
> >     Let $(\Omega,G)$ be a dynamical System with $G=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}_0$ (written as right Transformation Group). and $\Gamma$ be a semi-Group with composition $\circ$. A cocycle is a map $\gamma\colon\Omega\times G\to\Gamma$ with te property that for any $g_1,g_2\in G$ and $x\in\Omega$, the relation
> >     $$
> > \gamma(x,g_1g_2)=\gamma(xg_2,g_1)\circ\gamma(x,g_2)
> > $$
> >     is fulfilled.

Now, I would like to verify that the following is a cocycle:

Let $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^d$ be a function. Then 
$$
\gamma(x,n)=S_nf(x)=f(x)+f(T(x))+\ldots +f(T^{n-1}(x)) 
$$
is a cocycle over $\mathbb{N}_0$ with values in $\Gamma=\mathbb{R}^d$.

So, when I got it right, here we have

- $(\Omega,G)=(\Omega,\mathbb{N}_0)$,
- $(x,n)\mapsto xn$,
- $\gamma\colon \Omega\times\mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{R}^d$ with composition $\circ$
- $T\colon\Omega\to\Omega$

But how to Show that
$$
\gamma(x,n_1n_2)=S_{n_1n_2}f(x)=S_{n_1}f(xn_2)\circ S_{n_2}f(x)=\gamma(xn_2,n_1)\circ\gamma(x,n_2)?
$$

I am confused about all the different compositions:

We have

- $n_1n_2$ with $n_1, n_2\in\mathbb{N}_0$,
- $xn$ with $x\in\Omega, n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and
- and $\circ$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider $\mathbb R^d$ with addition (that is, in this case the group operation $\circ$ is addition)

We have
$$
\gamma(x,g_2)=f(x)+\cdots +f(T^{g_2-1}(x)) 
$$
and since $xg_2=T^{g_2}(x)$ (you need to choose the action like this), we also have
$$
\begin{split}
\gamma(xg_2,g_1)
&=f(xg_2)+\cdots +f(T^{g_1-1}(xg_2))\\
&=f(T^{g_2}(x))+\cdots +f(T^{g_1+g_2-1}(x)).
\end{split}
$$
Hence,
$$
\gamma(xg_2,g_1)+\gamma(x,g_2)=f(x)+\cdots +f(T^{g_1+g_2-1}(x))=\gamma(x,g_1+g_2).
$$